# Disaster Response Unit cars not deploying?

Tags: cities-skylines

It will increase from 0 to 10 very quickly and go back to zero. I tried placing a couple of them and every once and a while ONE car will deploy to look for survivors, is anyone else having this annoying glitch? Only the 3 helicopters are working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and it is possible your problem has been resolved by now, but I will put forth my findings anyway!

There are a couple of potential causes for your issue.

- If you are using the auto bulldoze mod, you need to *turn off* **burned buildings** otherwise the disaster units will not search the rubble. You can also get [this version](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=639486063) of auto bulldoze which is updated to work with the Natural Disasters DLC.
- If the roads are damaged and the ground vehicles cannot get to the disaster site, they will not leave. With that being said, **helicopters should still deploy**.